# MySQL: Select * where filename LIKE 'C:\Boston Office\User\SQL\RevitFile.rvt'

Tags: mysql

I have a file path like the one above, and I actually copied and pasted from my MySQL table. I know that the path is correct, but I can't get any results.

I have also tried

1. `'C:\\Boston Office\\User\\SQL\\RevitFile.rvt'`
2. `'%C:\Boston Office\User\SQL\RevitFile.rvt%'`
3. `'C:\Boston Office\User\SQL\RevitFile.rvt%'`

and all the above with double quotes. Why isn't this working?

Comment: 3 should read 'C:\Boston Office\User\SQL\RevitFile.rvt%', apologies

Comment: Jediah, you can edit your post... And please only use tags that are relevant to the software you're using. `sql-server` is the the same as `mysql`, which are you using?

Comment: You have a user named SQL?

Comment: Why don't you just look for the `filename like '%RevitFile.rvt%'`? See what that returns.

Comment: that is looking good! Will I have issues if for example I had two close files, such as RevitFile2 etc.?

Comment: @JediahLankitus are u sure C is typed on Latin? (it may be the same key on english and russian keyboard). just a thought

Comment: @WEI_DBA It is also a little inconvenient to not use the whole filepath (I am automating this in c# for alot of files, but it isn't that bad. Curious as to why the full path doesn't work though

Comment: What is the value of this settings: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes

Comment: Also, why are you using `LIKE`? What is the definition of the column `filename`?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto global: 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Session: 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I tried = as well, but it didn't have results so I tried like. The column filename is a bunch of strings, including the exact one I included (C:\Boston Office\User\SQL\RevitFile.rvt)

Comment: If `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` is enabled, you should not double the backslashes.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto it is working using '='. For anyone with this issue, use the command `SET sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES' ` to fix it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @UsagiMiyamoto I found that I could use the original file path after using the command `SET sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'`

Final answer:

1. `SET sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'`
2. `SELECT * FROM revit.fileindex where filename = 'C:\Boston Office\User\SQL\RevitFile.rvt'`

Appreciate the help from everyone :)